# WooCommerce: Display Category Name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, woocommerce-theming

Is there a way to display the product category name on the WooCommerce `archive-product.php` page.

My product category name is "Bracelets", and I'd like that to be displayed as a title on the page.

I'm using `wp_title()` currently:

```
<h1><?php wp_title(); ?></h1>
```

But that prints it to the page like this:

```
» Product Categories » Bracelets
```

I'm getting the parent page title and the catgeory name with separators in between them (above).

Is there any way I can get the title to print just "Bracelets"?

Any help with this is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You're looking for `single_term_title()`:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_term_title/

Answer (score 8):

Currently you can display product categories [this way](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product_category_list.html) (Wordpress 4.x):

```
<?php echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id()) ?>
```

Comment: If, for some reasons, you need to display the category name without the link : 
`<?php 
$current_cat =  strip_tags(wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id()));
echo $current_cat; 
?>`

Answer (score 5):

Use the **get_categories** function to retrieve categories name :-

You can use this code to display product categories name -

```
<?php global $post, $product;
    $categ = $product->get_categories();
    echo $categ; ?>
```

Comment: I downvoted because this method is obsolete since Wordpress 3.0. In 2019 you should definetely use @Igor Okto below answer <?php echo wc_get_product_category_list($product->get_id()) ?>

Answer (score 0):

I think it prints the breadcrumb, because it's hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb.

You could override in your theme the template Archive-product.php

```
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     */
    do_action( 'my_woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>
```

and create another action inside functions.php,

```
add_action( 'my_woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
add_action( 'my_woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_woocommerce_print_category_name', 20 );
```

Inside your functions.php you can also create a functions like this:

```
function my_woocommerce_print_category_name() {
    //You can implements a function for get category name...    
}
```